MUI AutoComplete with Checkboxes with RHF ( React Hook Form )
I'm using Material UI 6.1.10 with React Hook Form 7.53.2
I'm trying to have a re-usable AutoComplete field with ability to select multiple values.
problem is, if my AutoComplete doesn't have onChange prop, It's value always returns empty and I can't get the value of it.

I can fix this by adding onChange prop to it, but another problem rises, which is, when i select an option, checkboxes don't get selected and I can select the same option multiple times in my field.

I tried using AutoComplete field without checkboxes, but it doesn't matter, problem still stands, If I have onChange prop, seems like field can't figure out with options are selected, and if I remove onChange prop, field seems to know with options are selected but value is always empty.

I appreciate your help 
